# Getting attribute value from SimpleXMLElement object

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

This:

```
$newXMLdoc = new SimpleXMLElement($myXML);
```

Contains :

```
$newXMLdoc
: object(SimpleXMLElement) = 
  @attributes: array = 
    AMOUNT: string = 4444
```

I need to get the value of AMOUNT

So I am doing:

```
$newXMLdoc->xpath('@AMOUNT')
```

But instead of the value in AMOUNT which is 4444 I get:

```
: array = 
  0: object(SimpleXMLElement) = 
    @attributes: array = 
      AMOUNT: string = 4444
```

How can I get AMOUNT’s value? (it's ok amount's value is a string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `->xpath()` in SimpleXML is an array of objects.

Just do like this:

```
$amount = (string)array_pop($newXMLdoc->xpath('@AMOUNT'));
```